# Using mozilla experimental APIs with a polyfill

Tags: javascript, polyfills

While searching for a way to find out where I need to be inserting elements into an array, I found the `findIndex()` method on MDN. "Oh wow!" I thought to myself, "How have I never found this method before? This is incredibly useful."

So I added it to my code, which promptly crashed because `findIndex` is an experimental API that hasn't been implemented in Chrome yet. There is, however, a polyfill for it on MDN. What I'm wondering is this: how safe is it to use the experimental APIs in a piece of production code along with the polyfill? I've never used polyfills before, and I'm wondering if there's a chance that, somewhere down the line, a change will be made to how this API works and my code will stop working. Which would be bad.

Is it safe to use this API with a polyfill for browsers that don't support the method, or am I safer taking the polyfill and defining it internally as a function, gaining the functionality I need and shielding myself from potential changes, but losing any performance gains I might receive from letting native code do the work for me?

Source: [MDN page on findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: yes, the polyfill works just like the "real one" in all browsers, so go for it.

Comment: As noted in the docs, this is part of the forthcoming ECMAScript 6 standard. Until the spec is finalized, there's some risk, however it seems unlikely that there'll be much change if any. But no one here knows the future any better than you, so it comes down to your own comfort level.

Comment: ...and if you define your own function, you can always have it look for the native one and invoke that if found. Then at your leisure you can update your code to replace your function with a direct call.